# Android: How to get the name and photo from ContactsContract?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I am new to android, I need to get the the name and photo from the address book, and display them in a list view with ImageView and TextView. Been goolging around for hours, too many different answers, I am working on Android 2.1, what is the proper way to do it?

Regards,

Johnny